# casperjs error : [debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

So I have this website that I want to crawl using casperjs.
The url structure of the site is https://www.siteIwanttocrawl.com/?date=2016-04-16, this url will display all the content of the site posted on 16th April 2016.

I needed to crawl pages for 1 April 2015 to 31st march 2016. So I wrote the following casper script which starts with 2015-04-01, keeps adding one day and keeps crawling.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
        verbose: true,
        logLevel: 'debug'
    });
    casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0');

    var curdate = new Date(2015, 3, 1);
    var endDate = new Date(2016, 2, 31);
    var startUrl = 'http://www.google.com/';

    casper.spider = function(dateStr) {
        casper.open("http://www.siteIwanttocrawl.com/?date=" + dateStr).then(function() {

            self.echo("\n#########\n" + date + self.getCurrentUrl() + "\n#########\n")

            curdate.setDate(curdate.getDate() + 1);
            if (curdate <= endDate) {
                var month = curdate.getMonth() + 1;
                var date = curdate.getDate();
                if (month < 10) {
                    month = "0" + month;
                }
                if (date < 10) {
                    date = "0" + date;
                }

                dateStr = curdate.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + date;
                casper.spider(dateStr);
            }

        });
    }

    // Start spidering
    casper.start(startUrl, function() {
        casper.spider('2015-04-01');
    });

    // Start the run
    casper.run();
```

the response that I am getting is :

> casperjs th2.js
>       [info] [phantom] Starting...
>       [info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
>       [debug] [phantom] opening url: http://www.google.com/, HTTP GET
>       [debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.google.com/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
>       [debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ME0RV-XgDe-K8QfDpaGgBA, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
>       [debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ME0RV-XgDe-K8QfDpaGgBA&gws_rd=ssl, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
>       [debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ME0RV-XgDe-K8QfDpaGgBA&gws_rd=ssl"
>       [debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
>       [info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2 https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ME0RV-XgDe-K8QfDpaGgBA&gws_rd=ssl (HTTP 200)
>       [debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
>       [debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"

```
    > casperjs --version
    1.1.0-beta5

    > phantomjs --version
    2.1.1
```

Comment: Did you happen to find an answer/workaround for this? I'm running into something very similar with 1.1.1 & 2.1.1 versions

Comment: @ejuhjav No. Switched to scrapy.